# Using recursion to reverse a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function, debugging, recursion

Is there an alternative way to reversing a list in python using recursion? Here is my code :

```
revList=[]
def reverseList(listXS):
    if(len(listXS)==1):
        revList.append(listXS[0])
    else:
        current=  listXS.pop()
        revList.append(current)
        reverseList(listXS)
    return revList

testList= ["mouse","dog","cat"]
print(testList)
print(reverseList(testList))
```

Comment: Do you mean is there an alternative to recursion (yes, you can use iteration), or is there an alternative implementation that still uses recursion (also yes)? Is there some problem with your current code (aside from the fact that globally scoping `revList` will give you... interesting results on the next list you reverse)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he wants to know if there is an alternative implementation that makes use of a recursive algorithm.

Comment: @jlnabais there seems little point in speculating!

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, after reading it again I'm confused too, I thought he's intentions were more explicit when I first read it, my bad.

Comment: The OP wants a recursive solution *Is there an alternative way to reversing a list in python using recursion?* it is not *other than using recursion*

Comment: Why 4 upvotes for this silly question?? of course there is an alternative way

Comment: @wim, the OP provided their own working code and is asking for alternative ways to do it, what is wrong with that?

Comment: Because there is no clear problem.  Perhaps better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an alternative recursive approach:

```
def reverseList(listXS):
    return [] if not listXS else [listXS.pop()] + reverseList(listXS)
```

Or slicing:

```
def reverseList(listXS):
    return [] if not listXS else listXS[-1:] + reverseList(listXS[:-1])
```

If you wanted an inplace solution:

```
def reverseList(listXS, i=1):
    if i == len(listXS) - 1:
        return
    listXS[i-1], listXS[-i] = listXS[-i], listXS[i-1]
    reverseList(listXS, i+1)
```

reversing the original list:

```
In [22]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4,5]  
In [23]: reverseList(l)    
In [24]: l
Out[24]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]    
In [25]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
In [26]: reverseList(l)    
In [27]: l
Out[27]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: your answer is just what I was looking for !!! thank you very much !!!

Comment: @MichaelAndréSlimz, no worries, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_reverse.htm) for this:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5].reverse()
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion you can do it like this but it is basically implementing a for loop a different way

```
def rev(x,y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = []
    y.append(x.pop())
    if x:
        y = rev(x,y)
    return y

print rev([1,2,3,4,5],[])

[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This would usually be implemented with `y=None`, then `if y is None: y = []` inside the function, so you don't have to pass an empty list explicitly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good point. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
def rev_list(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    else:
        return l[-1:] + rev_list(l[:-1])

print(rev_list([1,2,3,4,5]))

[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is exactly the same logic as my own answer posted a long time before yours, you have a habit of copying answers

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I do not have a habit of coping. I do not even look what others have answered to an OP question, before I post mine. This is so simple a recursion, there is no invention in it, it is like multiplication table. so people a stealing from you when you multiply numbers? You are ridiculous in your accusation.